# How do I classify this data by year and region in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

So I have the following data:

[image]

I have 5 regions, and years 1998-2009. What I like to do is to classify countries each year by regions. I'm new at R so the only step I've taken so far is the following:

```
finalData$Region = factor(finalData$Region, levels = c('Former Socialist Bloc', 'Independent', 'Western Europe','Scandinavia', 'Former Yugoslavia'), levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

but I get this error:

> Error in factor(finalData$Region, levels = c("Former Socialist Bloc", 
>   :    formal argument "levels" matched by multiple actual arguments

Could please tell me how to fix this and an approach to how to do the classification? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "classify" ? Do you just want to order by , or something more complex ? What should like your result ?

Comment: I would like to separate them graphically in different classes(the classes will be the regions) and if it's possible to do that for each year.

Comment: By them I mean the countries.

Comment: graphically ?What do you mean ? Could you provide an exemple of your desired result ?

Comment: For example like this: [link] http://perclass.com/doc/guide/images/clas_sdsvc_multi.png

Comment: Please read this : [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a terribly formulated question. But I am going to imagine this is roughly what you want to do to give you an idea.

You have samples (rows) which are countries and you have some variables (columns) which are observations about these samples. You want to use all/multiple variables (multivariate analysis) to cluster the countries. If this is what you want to do, then below is one approach.

I am creating a *data.frame* with pseudo dataset.

```
dfr <- data.frame(Country=c("USA","UK","Germany","Austria","Taiwan","China","Japan","South Korea"),
                  Year=factor(c(2009,2009,2009,2010,2010,2010,2010,2011)),
                  Language=c("English","English","German","German","Chinese","Chinese","Japanese","Korean"),
                  Region=c("North America","Europe","Europe","Europe","Asia","Asia","Asia","Asia"))

> head(dfr)
  Country Year Language        Region
1     USA 2009  English North America
2      UK 2009  English        Europe
3 Germany 2009   German        Europe
4 Austria 2010   German        Europe
5  Taiwan 2010  Chinese          Asia
6   China 2010  Chinese          Asia
```

First thing you want to do is move the country names out to `row names` because country names are the sample labels and they are not observations.

```
rownames(dfr) <- dfr$Country
dfr$Country <- NULL
```

Now you want all the remaining variables to be numeric or factors. Do that manually and carefully. I only have categorical observations. Finally we want to 
recode all factors to integers. So that our final *data.frame* contains only numbers.

```
dfr1 <- as.data.frame(sapply(dfr,as.numeric))
rownames(dfr1) <- rownames(dfr)

> head(dfr1)
        Year Language Region
USA        1        2      3
UK         1        2      2
Germany    1        3      2
Austria    2        3      2
Taiwan     2        1      1
China      2        1      1
```

Now run some clustering algorithm. Here for example a PCA.

```
pc <- prcomp(dfr1)
pcval <- pc$x

> head(pcval)
                PC1        PC2         PC3
USA     -1.04369951  1.2743507  0.36120850
UK      -0.87597336  0.5087910 -0.25990844
Germany  0.06243255  0.8258430 -0.39728520
Austria  0.36452903  0.2660249  0.37429849
Taiwan  -1.34455665 -1.1336389  0.02793507
China   -1.34455665 -1.1336389  0.02793507
```

Combine the output principal components with original data.

```
pcval1 <- cbind(pcval,dfr)
rownames(pcval1) <- rownames(dfr)

> head(pcval1)
                PC1        PC2         PC3 Year Language        Region
USA     -1.04369951  1.2743507  0.36120850 2009  English North America
UK      -0.87597336  0.5087910 -0.25990844 2009  English        Europe
Germany  0.06243255  0.8258430 -0.39728520 2009   German        Europe
Austria  0.36452903  0.2660249  0.37429849 2010   German        Europe
Taiwan  -1.34455665 -1.1336389  0.02793507 2010  Chinese          Asia
China   -1.34455665 -1.1336389  0.02793507 2010  Chinese          Asia
```

What is PCA and what is going on here is clearly out of the scope of this answer. In short, it creates some new variables based on all your observed variables.

Scatterplot the principal components 1 and 2. Colour points by some variable. Say "Region". Add country names as text labels.

```
library(ggplot2)
pcval1$Country <- rownames(pcval1)

ggplot(pcval1,aes(x=PC1,y=PC2,colour=Region))+
  geom_point(size=3)+
  geom_text(aes(label=pcval1$Country),hjust=1.5)+
  theme_bw(base_size=15)
```

[image]

Now we see that countries have clustered together based on the observations in your dataset. We have the countries roughly grouping by Region. Obviously, there may or may not be any clustering depending on your data.

This is just an example. If you blindly follow this, you may be violating all sorts of statistical assumptions and what-not. You have to take into account what kind of data distributions you are dealing with and what clustering algorithm is suitable for that data etc.